# Three-line intersection symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators, relation-symbols

The symbol `\Cap` can be produced using the relevant packages.

Is there anyway I can create three-line intersection symbol `\CAP`, as shown in the picture below? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't know that symbol, and can't found it in Unicode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Operators_(Unicode_block) In what context did you find it?

Comment: @gildux -- I'm quite sure it isn't in Unicode.  I was the representative of STIPub who presented the request to Unicode to add most of the math symbols that were accepted into Unicode 4.0, and that wasn't among them.  If a properly documented request is made (requires published example in context, showing usage and meaning), it can be considered for addition.  It would then still require inclusion in an appropriate font.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In my opinion, it's necessary to put such symbols into the font file in the unicode way which may be useful for many people. And so for as I know, it's very easy to do so.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton Like M. Logic I appreciate when symbols are defined in Unicode because it's usefull for more people and even for TeX systems users (as one can easely post here whithout need of image, and ability to search some other sites)

Comment: @M.Logic -- While it may be relatively easy to put a symbol into a font (it's not, really, but let's give it the benefit of the doubt), it's not trivial, in most cases, to get it into Unicode.  It took nearly a year for the Unicode Technical Committee (UTC) to understand that a script "H" is different from an italic "H" (or any other, for that matter).  The trick that did it was an example based on the Hamiltonian equation, where the meaning of a script "H" is central.  Only a few UTC members have any mathematical background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't enough room inside `\Cap` to fit a third cap, so here is a built-from-scratch solution using Ti*k*Z. At present not available for use in subscripts, but that could be done using `\mathchoice` if desired. A command for `\CUP` is included as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\CAP}{\mathrel{\tikz[yscale=.18, xscale=.2, rotate=-90]{
  \draw[line cap=round](1,1)--(.4,1) arc(90:270:.5) -- (1,0)
    (1,.8)--(.4,.8) arc(90:270:.3) -- (1,.2)
    (1,.6)--(.4,.6) arc(90:270:.1) -- (1,.4);
}}}
\newcommand{\CUP}{\mathrel{\tikz[yscale=.18, xscale=.2, rotate=90]{
  \draw[line cap=round](1,1)--(.4,1) arc(90:270:.5) -- (1,0)
    (1,.8)--(.4,.8) arc(90:270:.3) -- (1,.2)
    (1,.6)--(.4,.6) arc(90:270:.1) -- (1,.4);
}}}


\begin{document}

$A\CAP B\Cap C\cap D$

$A\CUP B\Cup C\cup D$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\newlength{\capwidth}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\CAP}{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\f@size pt}
    \settowidth{\capwidth}{$\Cap$}
    \mathbin{\ooalign{%
        $\Cap$\cr%
        \hspace*{.5\capwidth}\makebox[0pt][l]{%
            \begin{picture}(1,1)
                \roundcap
                \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont 3}
                \put(0,0){\oval[.17](.36,1)[t]}
            \end{picture}%
        }%
    }}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(A \CAP B\)

\(A \Cap B\)
\end{document}
```